# Get total values of unique items in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I can get my tags. i.e., Pitcher, Pitcher, Catcher, Batter

I can get the unique ones. i.e., Pitcher, Catcher, Batter

How do I get?

Pitcher - 2

Batter - 1

Catcher - 1

```
const tags = attendance.map((entry) => entry.get('Tags')) // get tags

const uniqueTags = tags.filter((item, index) => tags.indexOf(item) === index) // get unique tags
```

Comment: It's my data. It's not the issue. Everything works fine.

Comment: I've already mentioned what the data looks like.

Pitcher

Pitcher

Catcher

Batter

Batter

Knowing what else is in attendance is irrelevant.

Comment: @JaromandaX I changed the last part to:
`=> <li key={key}>{key} - {value}</li>)`

Comment: @JaromandaX Still getting that damn 4 though...

Comment: @JaromandaX It's adding all of the items. Thats why it's a 4. There are only three unique items. Four total items.

Comment: tags = PitcherPitcherCatcherBatter

Comment: That is the output on the page when I run it. Sure, maybe it looks like that to the computer, but not the user

Answer (score 0):

Assuming tags ends up being `["Pitcher","Pitcher","Catcher","Batter"];`

```js
const tags = ["Pitcher","Pitcher","Catcher","Batter"];
const result = Object.entries(tags.reduce((r,t)=>(r[t]=(r[t]||0)+1,r),{})).map(([k,v])=>`<li key="${k}">${k} - ${v}</li>`).join('\n');
console.log(result);
```

Of course, as you can't see the exact content of tags the way you are using it, it may well be that tags is more like

```js
const tags = ["","Pitcher","","Pitcher","","Catcher","","Batter"];
const result = Object.entries(tags.reduce((r,t)=>(r[t]=(r[t]||0)+1,r),{})).map(([k,v])=>`<li key="${k}">${k} - ${v}</li>`).join('\n');
console.log(tags.join('')); // you can't see the empty tags here
console.log(result); // but this is the result
```

This is why I asked you to post what `attendance` is, to see what is happening with the data

But, with filter as I suggested ...

```js
const tags = ["","Pitcher","","Pitcher","","Catcher","","Batter"];
const result = Object.entries(tags.filter(t=>t).reduce((r,t)=>(r[t]=(r[t]||0)+1,r),{})).map(([k,v])=>`<li key="${k}">${k} - ${v}</li>`).join('\n');
console.log(tags.join('')); // you can't see the empty tags here
console.log(result); // with filter, everything is good again
```

Comment: So then how would you ignore empty values if that was an issue?

Answer (score -1):

If `tags` is an array of string (tags names), then you can use `reduce` to derive the desire output.

Example

```js
var tags = ['Pitcher', 'Pitcher', 'Catcher', 'Batter', 'Batter'];
var result = tags.reduce((acc, val) => {
  acc[val] = acc[val] || 0;
  acc[val] = acc[val] + 1;
  return acc;
}, {});
console.log(result);
```

Hope this will help!

**Edit**
To convert the final object into an array of string, you can use `.map`

```
Object.entries(result).map(([k, v]) => `${k}-${v}`);
```

Thanks for the heads up  `Jaromanda X`

Comment: Anything missing in the final output?

Comment: I'm doing this in react. This is the answer I see everywhere, but doesn't help with React. 

`Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {, Pitcher, Catcher, Batter})`

Comment: How you are using the final object?

Comment: <BlockText>{result}</BlockText>